# For-loop adds _BaseValue() to one of the range values

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a list of two unicode email addresses. Strangely enough, one of the two values comes out to be wrapped by _BaseValue when retrieved via a for-loop. See below.

```
for proj_ in mail_list:
    for who_ in proj_.who:  # where proj_.who = [u'first.last@us.email.com', u'first.last@gmail.com]
        print who_
```

This returns

```
first.last@us.email.com
**_BaseValue**('first.last@gmail.com')
```

If I evaluate who.b_val, the second element equates to first.last@gmail.com which is a non-unicode string.

Can you tell me why this happens, and how to avoid getting wrapped with _BaseValue()?

Comment: Where is mail_list coming from or how is it generated ?

Comment: under the hood ndb wraps and unwraps all properties with _BaseValue, for you to see it means something odd is going one when you construct/fetch mail_list.

Comment: @TimHoffman mail_list is an ndb query result object returned via cls.query(cls.another_datetimeproperty == None).fetch(999)

Comment: This is very odd, it seems you must be falling through an odd path when fetching results.  There is a caching layer (`_update_cache_from_query_result`) and the wrapping/unwrapping going on when you fetch entities.  Have set any cache behaviour explicitly ?

Comment: @TimHoffman No, no cache behavior set explicitly. In Eclipse Expressions view, the value of proj_.who clearly indicates both email addresses are unicode values, and _BaseVlue is not part of the values. That makes me wonder if the issue occurs when the list is iterated through.

Comment: Have a read of the definition of Property in google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py that will give you a better insight as to the role of _BaseValue . Is this when running in the SDK, or in production?

Comment: What property type is `who` defined as? And have you changed the property definition for `who` at some point?

Comment: "who" is ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True). Email address strings in multiple lists are combined (+) and put into this property as one list.

Comment: The issue happens while running in the SDK. When run in production, the developer console log shows the following error while looping through proj_.who, but I'm not sure what this even means.... 2014-05-21 21:32:24.465 ********************************************************************************
E 2014-05-21 21:32:24.465 ['/base/data/home/apps/s~myapplication/1.376006432792202000/external', '/base/data/home/apps/s~myapplication/1.376006432792202000', '/base/data/home/runti
E 2014-05-21 21:32:24.465 ********************************************************************************

Comment: You need to include the full stack trace from that log entry.  Also can you show how you are adding/concatenating emails, when you assign to the property.

Comment: @TimHoffman The error message shown above disappeared.(I think it was an unrelated issue) The BaseValue wrapping issue still exists. To rule out the possibility of issues arising from the method used to combine addresses into a list, I tested with a hard coded list of email addresses.(ie ['first.last@gmail.com', 'first.last@us.email.com'] Then saved it into an ndb repeated string property, and pulled it out and iterated through using for loop.. still the same issue.

Comment: The problem has to be in your code. I use repeated string properties all over the place and don't have this sort of problem, and many other people would to if it's a easily reproducible bug in string properties and iteration.  Need a explicit test (write and read) that can be tried elsewhere to replicate the problem.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks for giving this issue your thoughts. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have answer for you. I have been using appengine now since 2008 and haven't run into this sort of thing before.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using enumerate and pulling list elements using index. This didn't return the _BaseValue wrapper string for any of the elements returned.

Why who_ would have the _BaseValue is still a mystery.

```
for proj_ in mail_list:
    for n, who_ in enumerate(proj_.who):  # where proj_.who = [u'first.last@us.email.com', u'first.last@gmail.com]
        print proj_.who[n]
```